# Java webmail with Tor

Tags: mac, vpn, java

I use Tor browser on an OSX machine with a VPN.

I need java to work in order to access my webmail and my online banking service. I've tried adding my webmail address to whitelist and I've tried to allow scripts globally. To no avail.

Can you tell me what I´m doing wrong?

-yes I am a newcomer to internet anonymity and so on. I have searched all over for an answer to this question but could find none.

Comment: Can you clarify if you actually need Java, or just Javascript?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, thus I'll close it. If you have further additions, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/1556/edit) the question and it can be reopened.